# StreamWriter not writing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm attempting to create `.txt` file using `StreamWriter`.    I would like to be able to read in a text file, then automatically write the contents of that file to a new `.txt` file and store it to the applications root , with the same file name. (Hope that makes sense.)
Currently I am unable to find a solution to get it all working.  Please see my code.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //read in a .txt file//  this all works fine
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    this.Text = op.FileName;

    string filename = op.FileName;


    // not working //   
    //create new .txt file contaning module notes

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("..\\"op.FileName".txt" );
    using (writer)
    {
        writer.Write(richTextBox1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make your declaration within the using statement.

Comment: First of all you should fix your syntax errors, which your IDE points out for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with this, firstly:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("..\\"op.FileName".txt" );
```

Should be:

```
string filename = Path.GetFilename(op.FileName);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(".\\Notes\\" + filename);
```

Then another problem is here:

```
using (writer)
{
    writer.Write(richTextBox1);
}
```

Try:

```
using (writer)
{
    writer.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
}
```

You are basically trying to write a `RichTextBox` instance, which of course won't work as it expects a `string`.

You may also want to reconsider this:

```
if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
this.Text = op.FileName;
```

The `if` construct here will only consider that line after it, which puts the following lines into dangerous territory as if you cancel the open, it'll still run.

So putting it all together:

```
using (OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog())
{    
    op.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"; // Nice to have a filter

    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        this.Text = op.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFilename(op.FileName);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(".\\Notes\\" + filename);

        using (writer)
        {
            writer.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
        }
    }

} // Clean up the OpenFileDialog instance
```

This assumes the `Notes` directory exists. If it doesn't you'd have to create it. It also assumes that the directory is in the working directory which is *usually* the directory the executable is running from.

Comment: Thanks @Lloyd, the second part functions fine, however,                   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("..\\" + op.FileName);                          Gives an error of "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".  Any ideas what might be causing this?    thanks

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed Drop the ..\\ that says go up a level, coming from the OpenFileDialog you'll have a path already.

Comment: @Lloyd  Unfortunately still not creating the new .txt. I should write to the "debug" folder, right?  Thanks

Comment: Not if you're using an `OpenFileDialog`, should be able to save wherever you want (that's permissible).

Comment: @Lloyd  I'm using OpenFileDialog to open the original .TXT file, not to save the new instance of that file. Trying to recreate the imported file in a different location (if that makes sense).   Would using "op.Filename"  instead of a file path cause an issue?

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed Ahh yes that makes more sense now, yes it would. Where do you want to store this new file?

Comment: @Lloyd attempting to store the newly created files in a folder named notes within the applications root directory.

Comment: What do you define as root? Where the exe is? You generally should save elsewhere, to temp directory, program data, user data etc otherwise you could hit UAC permission issues.

Comment: @Lloyd Attempting to save to bin/debug/notes

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed Made some slight tweaks have a play with that. But remember by notes, you shouldn't usually save here anyhow.